# Jmeter : Issue with HTTP request returns java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: java, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am using an RSS feed generated by our test application to verify if there are any broken links on our website.

When I use these URLs in the HTTP sampler after some pre-processing (to split the URL to extract protocol, host, domain), most of the URL's are working just fine but I am facing issues in some **random cases** as explained below.

**for example:** below mentioned URLs throw URI exception. The **separator** between the highlighted text in these URLs mentioned below does **not** seem to a normal hyphen. It's some special character which I guess needs special handling.

**Failed URL from the feed**

https://abc.xyz.com/article/worksheet-development-**planning—manager**-preparation-10200/download/

https://abc.xyz.com/article/worksheet-development-**planning—worker**-preparation-10201/download/

**JMeter Result from Assertion Listener**

[See link below for JMeter Result from Assertion Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1usHV.png)

**URL gets encoded with some unexpected characters**

Comment: Yes, any non-ASCII characters (and even some ASCII characters) in a URL must be percent-encoded (except hostnames use punycode aka IDNA), and anything that produces purported URLs with non-ASCII characters is defective. See any of the dozens of specs going back 25 years or (easiest) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding .

Comment: Can you paste the screen shot of Http request configuration. I think the url is marked as encoding.

Comment: Based on the suggestion that Dmitri made, it is working fine now after using urlencode function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, this — symbol needs to be [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), to wit your URL path should look like

`article%252Fworksheet-development-planning%25E2%2580%2594manager-preparation-10200%252Fdownload%252F`

JMeter provides [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) which can perform URL-encoding of the passed parameter on the fly so you can use it directly in the "Path" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like:

```
${__urlencode(/article/worksheet-development-planning—manager-preparation-10200/download/)}
```

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It resolved the issues with the URL's that I had posted above. However, with this change, I started facing issues with URL's having date mentioned in them.

[see original url](https://abc.xyz.com/2020/03/06/hr-technologys-role-in-activating-diversity-inclusion)

After using __urlencode() function, url has become invalid and jmeter gives 404 error.

[see encoded url](https://abc.xyz.com/%2F2020%2F03%2F06%2Fhr-technologys-role-in-activating-diversity-inclusion)

I believe we need special handling in case of dates.

Comment: then use __urlencode() function only for the character which needs to be encoded